# Managing circuits beyond a basic level

Tags: design, parallel

I am very new to electronics so please go easy on me.

Whilst I have read a couple of electronics fundementals books so far, one of the things that confuses me the most about electronics is how voltage and current is managed based on the fact that current affects the whole circuit.

Here is a very simple explanation of a situation that would confuse me.

Say I had an LED which had a 330R resistor on a 5V DC supply and I decided to connect 4 more in parallel.  According to the laws of electronics, this should increase the current going into each LED (as according to my calculations, each LED now has a resistance of 66R - raising the current to *pop* levels).

What would be the best way to solve this?

A more complex example would be where I had a PIC driven circuit for detecting voltage and checking for a specific combination of keys (an electronic keypad).  I then decide to add in a power LED, in parallel, to determine if the circuit is even on.  I assume this would affect the voltage and current delivered in my original circuit and potentially break things, would it not?

If so, again, what would be the best way to solve this?

**I think, to sum it up, I am confused as to how circuits of any complexity are managed when adding a component can completely upset the balance of voltage and current.**

Comment: Ryall: it is not clear from the description, is the "1 + 4" circuit as illustrated in the following image? http://i.imgur.com/wLDrk.png

Comment: Ryall: what type of LED are you using? For instance, red/greeen/yellow/blue, normal brightness/high brightness?

Comment: Ryall: In "decided to connect 4 more in parallel", what are each of the 4? Is it resistor+LED, LED or resistor? In other words, which of the following component counts is it? 5 resistors + 5 LEDs / 5 resistors + 1 LED / 1 resistor + 5 LEDs ?

Comment: @Peter, it was 5+5 - I've got a much greater understanding of this stuff now. It's fun to look back on myself. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current through each LED would not change.  Each one would draw 5/330 or 15mA (I=V/R).  The power supply would have to supply 4*15mA or 60mA.  You didn't change the amount of current through any of the LEDs, all you did is add more of them in parallel.

Let's use a classic water analogy: you have a bucket of water with a single hole drilled in the bottom.  The amount of water flowing out of that hole  will not change if you drilled three more holes in the bottom.  The amount of water flowing out of the bucket, however, would quadruple.

Remember that in any circuit the current flowing through components in series will be the same, and the voltage across components in parallel will be the same. I think this is where your confusion lies.  Adding an LED across a power supply doesn't affect the voltage or current for the already-existing circuit just the same as plugging a radio into the outlet that a lamp is already plugged in to does not make the lamp get dimmer.

If you are still confused please comment and I will clarify. There's nothing wrong with wanting to learn. :-)

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you very much Andrew - my head is quite a bit less fuzzy now that you've cleared that up.

Comment: Although I'm sure I used to live in a house (not for very long) where plugging a radio into a wall socket which already had a lamp attached did make the lamp grow dimmer (though not for the reasons listed here).

Comment: current through each LED is not 5/330, it's (5 - Vf)/330 where Vf is the forward drop of the LED, usually 1.2-1.5V.

Comment: Yes, but he also doesn't have an LED with a resistance of 330 ohms. I was leaving the details out in order not to muddy the spirit of the question with pedantic details. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> and I decided to connect 4 more in
>   parallel. According to the laws of
>   electronics, this should increase the
>   current going into each LED

No, each LED would still have the same current through it, but the *total* current being used by all the LEDs together would be 4x as much.

> to add in a power LED, in parallel, to
>   determine if the circuit is even on. I
>   assume this would affect the voltage
>   and current delivered in my original
>   circuit and potentially break things,
>   would it not?

It could.  It depends on the output impedance (or [internal resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance)) of the power supply.  If the power supply has a low output impedance (as most do), then the droop in voltage by adding another load will not be very much.  A low impedance power supply is described as "stiff" because the voltage will not change very much as you change the loading.  A [LM7805](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7805.pdf) has an output impedance of 15 mΩ (thousandths of an ohm), for instance, which is very low.  It's designed to supply current to changing loads while not varying in voltage.

If it has a high output impedance, then increasing the load will cause the supply voltage to droop, which may affect the other loads.

Every component has some internal resistance.  Sometimes it matters, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you review your Kirchhoff's circuit laws:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws

As O Engenheiro has stated if the voltage source is considered to be ideal, its voltage source will not change. If you have read a few electronics books you will also know that a diode does not follow ohm's law. IE there is not a direct relationship between its current and voltage, however for quick and dirty calculations it can be assumed that its voltage drop would be .7V(assuming it is silicon, which it is likely the case)  seeing that your source is greater than this value(otherwise the diode could be treated as an open circuit)

Using KVL we know that VS - VResistor - VDiode = 0 => VResistor = 4.3V

and now since resistors do follow ohm's law:

I = VResistor/Resistance = 4.3V/330 = 13mA

However, the total current being drawn from the source will be 4X13mA = 52mA

Comment: this is correct, except for the numbers. The voltage drop for a normal Si diode is 0.7 V, but for LEDs it is in range 1.6 V to 2.4 V, depending on the type. For the red standard LEDs it is 1.6 V at the standard operating current.

Comment: LEDs are not Si devices. For instance the standard red LEDs are typically gallium arsenide phosphide (GaAsP) or Aluminium gallium arsenide (AlGaAs). Overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#Colors_and_materials

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's law: V = R x I

As you can see, voltage is directly proportional to resistence and current. The current through an ideal voltage source is completely determined by the external circuit. The ideal voltage source does not change its voltage. So, when the resistance value decreases, the current value must increase to maintain the same voltage value. The lower the resistance value, the greater is the current value.

Every load has an equivalent resistence. In your example, when you had only a LED with a 330R resistor (load), you had an Req = R1 (any value). When you put more LEDs and resistors, you changed the Req to R2. If R2 < R1, then the current will increase.

In the real world, the source voltage has a current limit that it can provide. If the current value increase a lot, you have to change the voltage source.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, it has further clarified this to me. I think what I didn't get was that the voltage across components in parallel is the same and that the circuit only drains the maximum amount of current it can at any one time. Previously, I had thought of current/voltage less like a bucket of water and more like a power-hose with a fixed current. In clarifying these points for me, you have both allowed me to fully appreciate the basics of how current and voltage works - something 2 starter electronics books failed to do.

Answer (score 2):

You bring up the point of a PIC.  The PIC's pins will either source or sink the current necessary to drive the output pin to 5V or 0V.

Let's say you have an LED's anode connected to a PIC output pin.  The cathode is then connected to ground through your current limiting resistor.  If you tell the PIC to output a 0, then we have 0V across the LED, so no current will flow through it.

Now, let's say you switch the output to a 1.  Now there's 5V across the LED and resistor; the output begins to *source* current.  The "1" connects the output pin to the VDD rail of the PIC, so that's where the current is coming from.

So now there's this burst of current where there was no current before.  The PIC is demanding more power.  Unfortunately, the power supply is "far away", and it takes some time for the PIC's demands to propagate across the board, and more time for the regulator to respond, and more time for the regulator's response to propagate back to the PIC's VDD pin.  During this time, there could be a catastrophic droop in the power supply at the VDD pin of the PIC.

To compensate for this, we use *bypass capacitors*.  Think of them as little puddles of charge.  When the output pin switches, the PIC will demand more current, and the capacitor will be able to provide some of it until the regulator can react.  This is why bypass caps must be placed as close as possible to the VDD/GND pins...they need to be able to react as fast as possible when the current gets switched on.